# Dynamic element not calling directive method on a AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

My intention with this directive is to create a Select-All directive, that can be attached to any kind of html element to be reused.

**Coffeescript:**

```
App.directive "selectAll", [ ->
  restrict: 'A',
  replace : true,
  scope: {
    attribute: '@',
    collection: '='
  },  
  link: (scope, element, attrs, model) ->
    scope.selected = false

    element.attr 'ng-click', 'toggle_selection()'
    element.html "<i class='icon-check icon-white''></i>Select All"

    scope.toggle_selection = () ->
      scope.selected = !scope.selected
      collection.forEach (item) ->
        item[attribute] = scope.selected
      scope.toggle_content()

    scope.toggle_content = () ->
      element.html("<i class='icon-check icon-white'></i>Select All") unless scope.selected
      element.html("<i class='icon-check-empty icon-white'></i>Unselect All") if scope.selected
]
```

**Javascript:**

```
App.directive("selectAll", [
    function() {
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
          attribute: '@',
          collection: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, model) {
          scope.selected = false;
          element.attr('ng-click', 'toggle_selection()');
          element.html("<i class='icon-check icon-white''></i>Select All");
          scope.toggle_selection = function() {
            scope.selected = !scope.selected;
            collection.forEach(function(item) {
              return item[attribute] = scope.selected;
            });
            return scope.toggle_content();
          };
          return scope.toggle_content = function() {
            if (!scope.selected) {
              element.html("<i class='icon-check icon-white'></i>Select All");
            }
            if (scope.selected) {
              return element.html("<i class='icon-check-empty icon-white'></i>Unselect All");
            }
          };
        }
      };
    }
  ]);
```

The problem is that the toggle_selection function is not being called. I tryied to call `$compile` on the element that I created dynamically but it raised an exception saying that compile is not defined.

Also if you have a better way to do what I'm doing please share the best practices, since I'm using Angular for less than a week.

Thank you!

Comment: Look at `template` property of directive documentation. What you are doing can be done in a directive template. The directive template can contain binding expression which can show\hide and change class based on state ($scope).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't discovered the reason, so I changed the approach to use the template atribute as suggested in commends by @Chandermanji

```
App.directive "selectall", [ ->
  restrict: 'E',
  replace : true,
  scope: {
    attribute: '@',
    collection: '='
  },
  template: '<div class="btn btn-large btn-inverse" ng-click="toggle_selection(collection, attribute)">' +
      '<i class="icon-check icon-white"></i>Select All' +
    '</div>',
  link: (scope, element, attrs, model) ->
    scope.selected = false

    scope.toggle_selection = (collection, attribute) ->
      scope.selected = !scope.selected
      scope.collection.forEach (item) ->
        item[attribute] = scope.selected
      scope.toggle_content()

    scope.toggle_content = () ->
      element.html("<i class='icon-check icon-white'></i>Select All") unless scope.selected
      element.html("<i class='icon-check-empty icon-white'></i>Unselect All") if scope.selected
]
```